# how to set an animation for all UIImageView instances by default

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimageview, core-animation

I want to write **a (only one)** method or category or something else about an Animation,

so that when I am setting any UIImageView's image property, the animation will be executed automatically.

any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can subclass UIImageview.
2. Add a animationProperty.
3. Create a animation block.
4. Call animation block from the setMethod of the animationProperty.

Answer (score 0):

As `image` is a property, you can use `KVO`.

First In the category add image-observer, and write your own animation method.